# Short for loop for fetching bash users

Tags: python, linux

A short python script i wrote to fetch users who are using bash. below is script. I don't know why its not working. Please share your ideas as to how this program is working inside.I am beginner in python and looking for lectures on data structures and algorithms. any answers are welcome. Thanks

```
f = open("/etc/passwd")

mainshell = '/bin/bash'
for line in f:
    field = line.split(:)
    shell = field[-1]
    user  = field[0]
    if shell = mainshell:
        print(user)
```

edit: I am getting no output. I tried to fetch values of variable shell and users and that exactly what i need but somehow if block is not working. Its not giving any error but just not working.

Comment: Please be specific on what is not working i.e. do you get no output or an error etc. A test data sample might help too.

Comment: i have edited my question

Comment: Something I noticed is you've got `if shell = mainshell` instead of `if shell == mainshell`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there with your script. But there are 2 reasons why its not working.

1. Your `if` statement is not doing a string comparison. You should be using  `==` not `=`
2. You compare the string `mainshell` with `shell`, but you assume `shell` does not contain whitespaces. But the string will probably look like this `/bin/bash`    (notice the whitespaces at the end?). This can be removed with  `shell = field[-1].strip()`

I think then your program should work fine :)

Comment: there was a trailing white space that was causing if block to do nothing. Thank you very much.